# How can i do the http post junit test with spring boot controller

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I would like to ask about how can i do the http post request with spring boot controller. My http body is a json, and then i try to make a http request in the junit test function.

```
package test.controller;

import test.dto.RequestInput;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@WebMvcTest(value = RequestInput.class, secure = false)
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testNewRequest() throws Exception {
        String request = "{\"Uuid\": \"try_test_1\"}";

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/test/request", new JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString(), ResponseEntity.class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity);
    }

}
```

However, i tried to make the input string which become a json,

```
public String inputJsonStringGetUuid (String inputJson) throws Exception{
        String Uuid;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RequestInput request;
        try {
            request = mapper.readValue(inputJson, RequestInput.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("stringToRequestInput() - Format Error - Process STOP.");
        }
        Uuid = request.getUuid();
        return Uuid;
    }
```

and i found it not work and flow below error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@44032fde; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@44032fde; line: 1, column: 2]

    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.postForEntity(TestRestTemplate.java:440)
    at bat.controller.ParticipantsControllerTest.testBatNewParticipants(ParticipantsControllerTest.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@44032fde; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1011)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1201)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    ... 37 more
```

Please help, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't use suitable response type, you can simply use `String` or other suitable types.
For example:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/test/request", request, String.class);
```